# Using an image as a background

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on wpf application , and i want to use the shape of an exsiting image . i made the background of the windows transparent and i added the image , and some buttons but when i excute the application nothing apears  .

here is the code

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Selen.Wpf.DemoApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="A propos "
    Height="300" Width="450" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" TitleForeground="#999988" Background="Transparent" 
    WindowStyle="None"  ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  AllowsTransparency="True" >

<Grid  >
    <Border CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Background="Cornsilk"/>
    <Image Height="300"  Width="450" Name="test" Source="test1.png"  Visibility="Visible" 
    Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button x:Name="projet"  Width="40" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="64,0,346,260" Click="projet_Click" Cursor="Hand" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="pro.png"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="equipe" Background="Transparent" Width="40"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="105,0,305,260" Click="equipe_Click" Cursor="Hand" >
        <Image Source="equ.png" Width="40" Height="40" ></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="outils" Width="40" Background="Transparent" Margin="146,0,264,260" Visibility="Visible" Click="outils_Click" Cursor="Hand" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Image Source="outi.png" Width="40" Height="40" ></Image>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="titr" Height="30" Width="350" Margin="10,67,90,203" FontSize="16"  TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="White" Text="Modélisation des surfaces topographique :" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="10,102,140,18" Text="le text sera met ici" Foreground="White" />
    <Image x:Name="image" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="328,130,22,70" />
</Grid>
```

how can i solve that problem ?
ps : i did already add the image to the project .

Comment: where do you have those images?

Comment: they are on the folder of the application

Comment: what is the folder name?

Comment: Selen.wpf.DemoApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Source="/ApplicationName;component/Images/imagename.png" .

Answer (score 0):

Change the build action of the images  to 'Resource'. Also your images path seems to be  wrong.

Your Project Setup should like this,

[image]

and XAML is

```
          <Grid  >
            <Border CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Background="Cornsilk"/>
            <Image Height="300"  Width="450" Name="test" Source="Images/test1.png"  Visibility="Visible" 
    Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button x:Name="projet"  Width="40" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="64,0,346,260" Click="projet_Click" Cursor="Hand" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="Images/equ.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="equipe" Background="Transparent" Width="40"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="105,0,305,260" Click="equipe_Click" Cursor="Hand" >
                <Image Source="Images/outi.png" Width="40" Height="40" ></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="outils" Width="40" Background="Transparent" Margin="146,0,264,260" Visibility="Visible" Click="outils_Click" Cursor="Hand" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Image Source="Images/pro.png" Width="40" Height="40" ></Image>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="titr" Height="30" Width="350" Margin="10,67,90,203" FontSize="16"  TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="White" Text="Modélisation des surfaces topographique :" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="10,102,140,18" Text="le text sera met ici" Foreground="White" />
            <Image x:Name="image" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="328,130,22,70" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: @M_M Check modified answer!

Answer (score 0):

Under the brush catagory in your pages properties Select the background (Has an image icon) 
Then set the image source to your picture. it should be in the drop down list

Comment: i added the image source on the properties page but it still doesn't apprea !

Comment: Go to the properties of the image and make sure its build action is set to resource

Comment: i can't find this property " build action " !

Comment: Right click your image in the solution explorer. Select properties. Build action should be the 1st or 2nd combo box in the properties pane